# C# OpenLDAP Error: unicodePwd: attribute type undefined

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, ldap, passwords, openldap

I am trying to change the user password of OpenLDAP from ASP.NET Core Web API using the library  `Novell.Directory.Ldap`. OpenLDAP is configured on Ubuntu 18.04 with SSL enabled. So I connect using the option `SecureSocketLayer = true` and `Port = 636`. Following is the code to change the password:

```
string oldPassword = '"' + OldPassword + '"'; 
string newPassword = '"' + NewPassword + '"'; 
var oldPasswordbytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(oldPassword);
var newPasswordbytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(newPassword);

LdapModification[] modifications = new LdapModification[2];
LdapAttribute deletePassword = new LdapAttribute("unicodePwd", oldPasswordbytes);
modifications[0] = new LdapModification(LdapModification.Delete, deletePassword);
LdapAttribute addPassword = new LdapAttribute("unicodePwd", newPasswordbytes );
modifications[1] = new LdapModification(LdapModification.Add, addPassword);
connection.Modify(userDn, modifications);
```

This code goes well with the AD domain. But for OpenLDAP it is giving error:

> unicodePwd: attribute type undefined

I tried `userPassword` instead of `unicodePwd` but the same type of error.
Does this error belong to an attribute not exist in OpenLDAP or I cannot use this code for OpenLDAP? How to change the OpenLDAP user password using C# library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Active Directory requires the special format for the password value. For OpenLDAP, just use a regular string without quotes.

Also, OpenLDAP uses the `userPassword` attribute.